# Google Drive API Console: Error saving Drive UI integration page

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have a webapp in production that interacts with Google Drive through Google Drive API.

I need to change some settings in Drive interaction but **I can't save**.

When I save the *Drive UI integration* page, I receive this error:

> There's a problem at our end.
>
> Please try again. If the problem persists, please let us know using
>   the "Send feedback" link below. Thanks!

(spying Network console: there is an Internal Server Error in a POST call)

I tried to send feedback for months: nobody answers and the bug is still there.

I tried also to create another project: I can save the first time but then the bug returns.

How can I do? Has someone the same problem?

Is there a way to receive a reply from Google?  Is there some workaround?

Thank you.

Comment: This is happening to me too. It shows an error when I submit even though I filled out all the required fields correctly. I've tried several times over a period of weeks and varying the contents of the fields, nothing works... somewhat disheartening to see this asked in 2018 and still not fixed! I'll start a bounty...

Comment: For the record I tried filing a bug as well, but was told to use 'Send feedback' instead. I did that, but heard nothing back. It's been a couple of weeks now, there's no response, and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Here's the link to the bug I filed which was closed without it being fixed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/156325006

Answer (score 1):

i think that problem must be `Client ID`

before adding `Client ID`, go to the `Credentials` -> `OAuth 2.0 Client IDs`
then select edit your `Client ID`. after that your production site url add to `Authorized JavaScript origins` and `Authorized redirect URIs`.

then enter your `Client ID` in `Drive UI integration page`

Answer (score 1):

For myself trying to get the Drive UI configured I noticed a couple of errors (that don't have any specific error messages)

1. When adding in an Open URL it has to be a valid domain, so for instance I tried to test it out with local host, to no avail. However something like `https://devbox.app.com` worked, but something like `https://localhost:8888` does not. Even though `https://localhost` is a valid javascript origin in the client_id configuration (at least for the app I am working on, not sure about other apps), localhost doesn't work as an open URL.
2. When adding in the mimeTypes it needs to be in the format */* and can include custom mimeTypes like `application/custom+xml` and `application/custom-name+json` not sure for other custom types that are not in a particular format like `xml` or `json`. Also not sure about wildcards.
3. When adding in file extensions do not add in the '.' just the name of the file extension.
4. The app icon I found only failed to upload the image when the image wasn't the exact dimensions, I actually ended up editing some icons in photoshop to change the pixel x pixel values as a quick work around during dev.

That worked for me to get it to save and I tested it with a file that had a custom mimeType (`application/custom-name+xml` specifically) and custom file extension!

Comment: Thank you. I resolved but I don't know how. Maybe it was a Google bug or maybe your answer is the correct one.
I don't know. Sorry.